# Syntastic not detecting errors

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting, syntastic

I am new to VIM. I have successfully installed pathogen and with the pathogen i install NERDTree, snimate, vim airline, vim snippets etc all are working fine. But when i tried **syntastic** its not detecting any errors i follow the directions for their github repository. https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic

Here is my .vimrc for syntastic
[image]

**:h syntastic is not working but :SyntasticInfo is working**
[image]
Here is my little ruby script and syntastic is not detecting any errors
[image]

Comment: For the help part: if you use pathogen you need to run `:Helptags` whenever you install new plugins or upgrade the existing ones, to (re)generate `tags` files for the docs.

Comment: i write :Helptags it gives nothing but when i gave :helptags it's asking about arguments...

Comment: Try `:help syntastic` now.

Comment: What do you get running `:SyntasticInfo`?